# What's wrong with my method of giving medals with reaching certain score?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

Hello I am new to all of this and just need a little help. I have 4 medals that the player should see when reaching certain levels. The problem that I have noticed is that I may reach a score of 20 and get the first medal but if I reach the next score for medal_02 it still shows medal_01. I believe it may be because I tell it to show medal_01 if (score >= 20) but say nothing if it is the next score so since it is technically still greater than 20 it will show medal_01.

Thank you

```
if(_score >= 2){
    SKSpriteNode *medal = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"medal_1"];
    medal.position = CGPointMake( CGRectGetMaxX( self.frame )*1/4 + 23, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + 23);
    [gameOver addChild:medal];
}else if(_score >= 4){
    SKSpriteNode *medal = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"medal_2"];
    medal.position = CGPointMake( CGRectGetMaxX( self.frame )*1/4 + 23, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + 23);
    [gameOver addChild:medal];
}else if(_score >= 30){
    SKSpriteNode *medal = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"medal_3"];
    medal.position = CGPointMake( CGRectGetMaxX( self.frame )*1/4 + 23, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + 23);
    [gameOver addChild:medal];
}else if(_score >= 50){
    SKSpriteNode *medal = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"medal_4"];
    medal.position = CGPointMake( CGRectGetMaxX( self.frame )*1/4 + 23, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + 23);
    [gameOver addChild:medal];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should reverse the order of your `if`s; your first one will be true for the first medal, but stay true thereafter, preventing any of the `if`s for the other medals to get tested.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you can make method that will create medal.

```
- (void)setMedalWithName:(NSString *)medalName
{
    SKSpriteNode *medal = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:medalName];
    medal.position = CGPointMake( CGRectGetMaxX( self.frame )*1/4 + 23, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + 23);
    [gameOver addChild:medal];
}
```

after this i don't know why did you check if score >=, if user can reach any level, then you needn't to check. You should check if current score is some number. IF there is case, that user can skip score number, than need to check

```
if (_score >= 2 && _score < 4)  
{
   [self setMedalWithName:"medal_1"];
}
else if (_score >= 4 && _score < 10)
{
   [self setMedalWithName:"medal_2"];
}
```

but you also can use this pseudocode:

```
/// method for calling
if (_score == 50)
{
 [self setMedalWithName:"medal_4"];
}
else if(_score == 25) 
{
///etc
}
```

Comment: `gameOver` may be local to the original method. It would probably be better to return the medal and let the caller do the `addChild:`